# How to display multiple contents in one panel

Tags: php

I am fairly new to php and web programming. I am seeking to create a section on my web page like the following:
[image] 
As you see in the picture, I have two buttons on top of the pane. When I click each button, I want relevant content to be displayed in content section, without refreshing the page. How can I do this in PHP? What do I need to use (e.g. AJAX, etc.)?

Comment: you could do something like a href to: `?page=usefullinks` and `?page=news` and then inside the content put: `<?php if($_GET['page'] == 'usefullinks'){ include 'usefullinks.php'; }?>` which loads a different php file into your content.

Comment: does it occur without refreshing the page?

Comment: No thats not possible in php, then you would need to use Javascript / or since its news (which is probaly dynamic?) Ajax

Comment: Yes preferably dynamic content. How can Javascript do this? Can you give me a hint please?

Comment: Well if it's dynamic (from databases) you should use Ajax. and I can't help you with that, not very familiar with Ajax.

Comment: I want to do it the way it's done in [link](http://fatemiyon.ir). there is a right part with two buttons each showing their relevant content when clicked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Googled up a solution for you, a good alternative would be using [jQuery](http://jquery.com/)
with the following code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$('#someButton').click(function(){
   $("#content").load("file.php");
   return false;
});
</script>
```

where `somebutton` would be the `ID` of your button, and `content` would be the `ID` of your main `<div>`. This script will load `file.php` into your main `<div>`.

It basicly creates a Ajax request for the file, all within the `load()` jQuery function.